# Next/Prev links not working on Wordpress pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a static front page on my wordpress site and am trying to get pagination working.

The pagination actually works if I manually go to the address (/2/, /3/ etc) but the next_posts_link and previous_posts_links don't work at all.

Could anyone pinpoint what my error is here?

```
        <?php $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
            'category__in'=> $cat,
            'paged' => $paged,
            );

        $featured_query = new WP_Query($args);

        while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : $featured_query->the_post();
        ?>

           <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts', $featured_query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>

            <?php if(is_paged()) { ?> 
            <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts', $featured_query->max_num_pages ); } ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your scripts , it maybe and actual script file that you can't reach , inspect that certain element.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args_blog = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'paged' => $paged,
                'posts_per_page' =>  get_option('posts_per_page ')
                );
                $query_blog = new WP_Query( $args_blog );
                if($query_blog->have_posts()) : while($query_blog->have_posts()) : $query_blog->the_post();
           ?>
                       <div class="pagination">
                           <?php
                    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                    echo paginate_links( array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'prev_text'          => __('Prev'),
                'next_text'          => __('Next'),
                'total' => $query_blog->max_num_pages
            ) );
            ?> 
                        </div>
                        <?php
                else :
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
                endif;
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

You should call `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` after post link see updated code:

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
    'category__in'=> $cat,
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$featured_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : $featured_query->the_post();
?>

<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() ); ?>

<?php endwhile;?>

<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts', $featured_query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>

<?php if(is_paged()) { ?> 
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts', $featured_query->max_num_pages ); } ?></div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```